# Implement a method in java mysql database connection class to use preparedStatements

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I have created a database connection class in my project to create and share database instance across the all class in the project.

Database connection obtained using this code

```
void createConnection(){
    try{
        connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb", "root", "");
        System.out.println("Connected");
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Failed");
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

Then I created a method to insert values to database using prepared statements as follows

```
public boolean execAction(String query){
    try {
        pstatement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(query);
        pstatement.execute(query);
        System.out.println("Values inserted");
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(databaseHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("Values insertion failed");
        return false;
    } finally {

    }
```

I want to find a way to pass preparedstatement variable values to this method.

Comment: Is your `execAction()` generic method which accepts any values or targeting for one table?

Comment: it is a generic method which can accept any value

Answer (score 0):

**If you are looking for `execAction(String query)` to handle for any database table**, then you need to write quite complex logic to check which datatype (i.e., blob, int, string, etc..) and it is not a good idea to reinvent something again. It can be nicely and easily handled if **you use any of the ORM (Object to Relational Mapping) tools like Hibernate**, etc.

The ORM concept is that you need to map each Model (Entity) class to a table in the database and the framework will handle all boilerplate code (i.e., adding `preparedstatement`.`setString()`, `setInt()`, etc..).

> Is there a way to get connection object in another class if I share a
>   database class instance through the overall project?

It is not a good practice to share a single connection object across the whole application, rather `return` different connection objects as shown below, Also, ensure that you need to close the connection by calling close().

One more point is that you might need to setup connection-pool otherwise, you will end up with errors.

```
public class DBUtil {

  public static Connection createConnection(){
    try{
       Connection connection = (Connection) DriverManager.
               getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb", 
                    "root", "");
        System.out.println("Connected");
        return connection;
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Failed");
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

  public static void closeConnection(Connection conn) {
        conn.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get connection object in another class if I share a database class instance through the overall project?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find a way to pass preparedstatement variable values to this method.

In general, you can pass a variable to another method as parameter or you can access variable if it is declared at class level.

I do not know the exact details of the query and its supplying parameters. See an example which explains the use of Prepared Statement.

[Example](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/): See more details in the link

```
    private static void insertRecordIntoTable() throws SQLException {

    Connection dbConnection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

    String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER"
            + "(USER_ID, USERNAME, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE) VALUES"
            + "(?,?,?,?)";

    try {
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);

        preparedStatement.setInt(1, 11);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, "mkyong");
        preparedStatement.setString(3, "system");
        preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4, getCurrentTimeStamp());

        // execute insert SQL stetement
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        System.out.println("Record is inserted into DBUSER table!");

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    } finally {

        if (preparedStatement != null) {
            preparedStatement.close();
        }

        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }

    }

}
```

> Is there a way to get connection object in another class if I share a database class instance through the overall project?

If you want to share connection among different classes or project level, you can create connection object using singleton pattern which will give the flexibility to share one connection for all the classes.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be:
First think about what you need this method to do.  Does it only need to take a single values, or many? Are the parameters of the same type?

Once you've got that, decide what data structure best represents this. Since PreparedStatement references parameters by index, if you want many values you probably want a list of some kind.  If each entry needs a type as well, you probably want to create a data class to hold that and the value in one place.

Since this looks like a programming assignment, I won't write the code for you, but that would give me something like this as a starting point:

```
public class DatabaseHandler {
    public boolean execAction(String query, List<PreparedStatementArgument> arguments){
        // code here
    }
}

class PreparedStatementArgument {
    private final PreparedStatementArgumentType type;
    private final Object value;

    // Constructor, getters
}

enum PreparedStatementArgumentType {
    INT, STRING; //etc
}
```

You might also consider using polymorphism for the PreparedStatementArguments, depending how complex you're prepared for this to get.

If this *isn't* a programming assignment, please be aware that the problem with a method like this is that it can't validate the parameters its given match the SQL - this makes it harder to spot if there's a mismatch, and is likely to make your application more error prone in the long run.